# Syntax error when importing array element into scope

Tags: php, closures, scope

I'm trying to import a variable into my closure with the help of the `use` keyword. But the parser is complaining about the bracket. Are array elements not allowed when you want to import variables into scope? Am I only allowed to import **full** variables (i.e., the `$_POST` itself)?

```
$data = array_map(function($key, $value) use ($tv, $_POST['entity'] as $entity) {
...
}, $keys, $values);
```

Error is: *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ')'*.

Comment: `$_POST` is a superglobal anyway...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol D'oh!

Comment: It's a shame that the syntax `function ... use` is still officially undocumented.

Comment: @AmalMurali I (ab)use it all the time. I prefer `array_map` to `foreach` :)

Comment: @silkfire: Me too. I was just saying that `...use()` is officially undocumented. Well, [it *is*](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), but that doesn't explain it in detail. The only "official" thing I could find was the [RFC about closures here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures).

Comment: @AmalMurali: It's documented right here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php  `Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the use language construct.`  It might not be documented very well, but it is there.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: I've read that (the part before Example #3). That doesn't really explain `use` in detail. Maybe I should've reworded it as: "poorly documented".

Comment: @AmalMurali: Yeah.  It's in there, but it's not really explained well at all.  Might as well be undocumented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_POST['entity'] as $entity
```

You can't do that.  You can only `use` variables, not array indexes.

The best thing to do is to save `$_POST['entity']` into a variable, then add that to the `use` statement.

```
$entity = $_POST['entity'];
$data = array_map(function($key, $value) use ($tv, $entity) {
    //...
}, $keys, $values);
```

Thing is, `$_POST` is actually a [superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), meaning it exists in *any* scope.

```
$data = array_map(function($key, $value) use ($tv) {
    $entity = $_POST['entity'];
    //...
}, $keys, $values);
```

Comment: Both are great answers, I can't decide which one to accept

Comment: @silkfire: Whichever one helped you more.  No hard feelings if it's the other one ;)

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST['entity']` is indeed not a *variable*, it's an index into an array. You cannot `use` that. Think about what the result should be like. Does that mean you can only access `$_POST['entity']` inside the closure, but not other indices in `$_POST`? Hardly makes sense. Just `$_POST` would be possible. However, `$_POST` is a superglobal to begin with, it's in scope *everywhere*. No need to `use` it.